# Retrieve values from jsp table

Tags: html, jsp, javabeans

I'm new to jsp and I'm trying to present the results of my database to a table in my jsp page. This looks like it works well as it presents all the elements correctly ! The problem is that I also want to to have a separate button and when I'm clicking it , I want the satatus of the line the button belongs to , to be converted from "unconfirmed" to "confirmed", but when I'm pressing it all the records turned to "confirmed" and not only the one the button belongs to !

My jsp code:

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Status</th>

        </tr>
        <%
        while(rs.next()){%>
                <td> <%=rs.getString("username") %></td>
                <td> <%=rs.getString("role") %></td>
                <td> <%=rs.getString("firstname") %></td>
                <td> <%=rs.getString("lastname") %></td>
                <td> <%=rs.getString("email") %></td>
                <td> <%=rs.getString("phone") %></td>
                <td> <%=rs.getString("status") %></td>
                <% if(rs.getString("status").equals("unconfirmed")){%>
                <td><input type="button" name="users" onclick="<%Bean.changeStatus(rs.getString("username"));%>"</td>
                <% }
                  else{ %>
                  <td>Check</td>
                  <% } %>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

And .java code:

```
 public void changeStatus(String us){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement state = null;
        String query = null;
        try{
            state=this.getConn().createStatement();
            query="update users set status='confirmed' where username='"+us+"'";
            int rowsEffected = state.executeUpdate(query);
        }catch(SQLException e){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a single `listener` on the table. When it gets a click from an input with a button that has a name of "**unconfirmed**" and value "**unconfirmed**", change its value to "**confirmed**". Get rid of the input's id (they aren't used for anything here), or make them all unique.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function handleClick(evt) {
  var node = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if (node.name == 'unconfirmed') {
    node.value = "confirmed";
  }
}

</script>

<table id="table1" border="1" onclick="handleClick(event);">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Select
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr> 
           <td>
               <form name="f1" action="#" >
                <input id="UnConfirmed1" type="submit" name="unconfirmed" value="UnConfirmed">
               </form>
       <tr> 
           <td>
               <form name="f2" action="#" >
                <input id="UnConfirmed2" type="submit" name="unconfirmed" value="UnConfirmed">
               </form>
       <tr> 
           <td>
               <form name="f3" action="#" >
                <input id="UnConfirmed3" type="submit" name="unconfirmed" value="onfirmed">
               </form>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have a button in every line that it was supposed to change the status of this line , but it doesn't ! My table is also dynamic ! The buttons are appeared only in lines that the status is "unconfirmed" ! In the lines that status is "confirmed" appears a check rather than the button !

Comment: @gimbo yes, that you can modify basedon if else condition, but the base is there for you to start now.

Comment: Could you explain it a little more ! I was a kind of confused !!